# Process two strings per line, data and process in single bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have a working solution already with a while read IFS processing a csv file, but I'd like to have it all in a **single bash script** as the input data never changes.

The data is a list of ip addresses and names;

```
10.0.0.1,server1
10.0.0.2,server2
172.16.0.1,server3
192.168.0.1,server4
```

The process itself will run a ping/curl/wget as required, all the while echoing out which server and test it is doing.

I can run the IP list on its own in the same file using a list function and reading the items, but then I don't get the server friendly name echoed out.  So my question is, how should I approach this?  I was thinking create the data array then parse in to a read somehow and split the tokens, but not sure how.  Thought about writing the data out to a temp file then reading it in again and deleting the tmp file afterwards, but this seems messy.  Any pointers appreciated.

In terms of a working solution (if someone wanted to provide instead of just advising), the output of the above data could just be echoed out like this;

```
Testing: $server, IP address: $ip, test 1.
```

Then I will just sub the tests as required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include your data directly in a script instead of reading it from a separate file, and you're already using a loop to read the existing data, the easiest way is probably just copy and pasting the data file's contents into a heredoc that the loop reads instead:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -i testno=1 # Make testno an integer variable that uses arithmetic expansion
while IFS=, read -r ip server; do
    echo "Testing: $server, IP address: $ip, test $testno"
    testno+=1
done <<EOF
10.0.0.1,server1
10.0.0.2,server2
172.16.0.1,server3
192.168.0.1,server4
EOF
```

which will display

```
Testing: server1, IP address: 10.0.0.1, test 1
Testing: server2, IP address: 10.0.0.2, test 2
Testing: server3, IP address: 172.16.0.1, test 3
Testing: server4, IP address: 192.168.0.1, test 4
```